# Uploading django app to digitalocean server: 502 bad gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I'm using the following [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/django-web-server-publish-tutorial/) to upload a django webapp to a digital ocean server. Everything seems fine while entering the following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade django
service gunicorn restart
```

According to the tutorial I now should be able to see my webpage (without the bootstrap theme/fonts) after refreshing the host ip in my browser. Instead I get the following error:

[image]

I've looked up the nginx error.log in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and it says the following:

```
2017/01/20 08:18:23 [error] 9342#0: *38 recv() failed (104: 
Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from 
upstream, client: 92.111.75.86, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "104.236.68.12"
```

**Question:** How do I fix this 502 bad gateway so that my site works properly? I've tried to add `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['104.236.68.12']` to settings.py already and I've also tried to create a droplet with ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: What is your config of nginx and gunicorn, it need more information to help you, update your post with that information please.

Comment: @juliansalas sure! Where can I find them? I'm a complete beginner..

Comment: Comment your current nginx and service file config, check service log file

Comment: @sideffect0 I can't locate the file you're talking about sorry.. I tried to access the gunicorn file though filezilla says: `Directory /var/log/gunicorn: permission denied`

Comment: If u are using upstart its in /var/log/upstart/

Comment: @sideffect0 Trying to find the service conf file in `var/log/upstart`; it's not there. Strangely enough I can't open anything in upstart. Example: `/var/log/upstart/network-interface-security-network-interface_eth0.log: open for read: permission denied`

Comment: Try to use ssh via putty only shell can help you debugging this

Comment: @sideffect0 I'm on a mac unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

You should add the IP address of your DigitalOcean droplet to the **ALLOWED_HOSTS** variable in your Django settings. Starting from your nginx log, I would set:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['104.236.68.12']
```

P.S: Consider to adopt Docker for the deployment of your django app

Comment: I already tried that like I mentioned in my question! (I'll edit my question so that it's more clear.)

Comment: The variable name is not ALLOWED_DOMAINS but ALLOWED_HOSTS

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry guys. This solved the issue...

Dragging my django app in filezilla to

```
home/django/django_project
```

instead of:

```
home/django/django_project/django_project
```

Basically wasn't precise enough when reading the tutorial, so sorry!

Comment: Try to use ssh on Mac , it will help you lot !

Answer (score 0):

Good day:
In the settings.py exactly in
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

This will make it collect all the ips.